# Automate Jenkins to create slave

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I am new to `Jenkins` and I stumbled upon a use case for my company. I am having Jenkins server running on AWS EC2 instance on `us-west-1` and my company's in east coast. I want to create a slave in us-east region of AWS through automation. Is there any scripted way to do this in an efficient way ?

Comment: You could checkout the [Amazon EC2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin). It can spawn ec2 slaves on demand and shut them down after some unused time.

Comment: That would solve my issue. Thanks @fishi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @fishi
the [EC2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) helped me to solve the issue of launching Jenkins Slaves automatically